# can php be used to send two different emails

Tags: php, email, loops, mailto

I have a php documnet that submits a form and sends a conformation message to the user and also sends a the message with other data to the site owner.

I am using the mail() function. This works fine but it only sends the first message. 
So as to can imaging the format would be like this

retrieve POST data -> Process data -> send plain copy to site owner -> send html conformation to user.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
//send site owners message
mail('xxxsiteownersemailxxx',$name.' has sent you a message',$msg);
//send users message
$subject = 'Your message has been received';
$to = $email;
$from = 'Queries @ xxxcompnay namexxx';
$headers = "From: Sparkle Lilys \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$msg = 'build in html email';
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
```

I know that multiple emails can be sent using loops but I want to send two different emails, could this be done without a loop or if not what would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: How do you know only one gets send?

Comment: I used my email address as the $to variable in both

Comment: Yes, it definitely can

Comment: which one is being sent correctly?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with delivering the email not sending it. Do you get any errors when running this script? Can you check what does `mail()` return?

Comment: You want to send two different messages to the same email? @PaulLedger

Comment: Did you read your MTA logs to find out what happenned to the other one? You don't check the return code from mail() - why not?

Comment: Not sure how to check the return code form the mail function never had a problem with it before and @ChosenWann obliviously I dont want to send the message to myself twice its for testing purposes

Comment: Use the PHPMailer class (found here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and switch on debugging. Please post the errors you get here so that we can help you.